# how to get the imageUrlString from NSArray

Tags: ios, ios6

After parsing elements from Remote XML File, I got the list of elements and its values in `NSArray`. Since the array contains more elements and values like this,

```
success; products=<AGSProducts 0x7189020; name='category1';imageIdentifier='1'; imageUrlString='http://myimage.com/images/img1.png'; subProducts=>
```

I need to get the `imageUrlString` from this NSArrray. how to get this specific imageUrlString alone from those Array.

**MyViewController**

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *xmlProductsResults;

[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myxml.com/Category.xml"];
EGSParser *parser = [[EGSParser alloc] init];
if ([parser loadXMLByURL:url]){
  self.xmlProductsResults = parser.products;
  NSArray *myArray = [_xmlProductsResults objectAtIndex:0];
  NSLog(@"success; products=%@", myArray);
}
```

Kindly suggest me an idea

Comment: Do some string manipulation to get that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps.

**Edit 2**

```
NSString *string = [myArray description];
NSString *url = nil;
NSScanner *parser = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
[parser scanUpToString:@"imageUrlString" intoString:nil];

if (![parser isAtEnd]) {
    [parser scanUpToString:@"=" intoString:nil];
    NSCharacterSet *charset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\"'"];
    [parser scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:nil];
    [parser scanCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:nil];
    [parser scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:&url];

}

NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
```

Comment: My App gets terminate with error `[AGSProduct copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71622b0`

Comment: Nope terminates with `[AGSProduct objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x719e350`

Answer (score 1):

Convert your response in a dictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [myString JSONValue];
```

From the dic you can get the value of `imageUrlString`

Comment: Can you say what that JSONValue mean. FYI am using an XML file

Comment: its a parser which converts ur string in dict.

Comment: am getting error in that statement `JSONValue` as  `No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'JSONValue'` Do i need to import anything for this?

Comment: A good way is to get your response in dictionary instead of array

Comment: yes u need to include jsonparser classes. u can download from this url https://github.com/colman01/JsonParser

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING:** This is not best-practice, but would do the trick and it is efficient...

```
NSString *result = @"";
NSRange r1 = [myString rangeOfString:@"imageUrlString='"];
if(r1.location != NSNotFound)
{
    result = [myString substringFromIndex:r1.location+r1.length];
    NSRange r2 = [result rangeOfString:@"'"];
    if(r2.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        result = [result substringToIndex:r2.location];
    }
    else
    {
        result = @"";
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Comment: My App gets terminated with error `[AGSProduct rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74b45b0`

Comment: Make sure that myString is a NSString and not other type... Try this before: NSString *myString = (NSString *)myOldStringObj;

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
    //NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"<AGSProducts 0x7189020; name='category1';imageIdentifier='1'; imageUrlString='http://myimage.com/images/img1.png'; subProducts=>", nil];
    //NSString *imgURL= [arr objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *imgURL=[_xmlProductsResults objectAtIndex:0];

    imgURL = [imgURL substringFromIndex:[imgURL rangeOfString:@"imageUrlString="].location+[@"imageUrlString=" length]+1];
    imgURL = [imgURL substringToIndex:[imgURL rangeOfString:@";"].location-1];
    NSLog(@"%@",imgURL);
```

Comment: Nope Bhargavi, Getting an error `[AGSProduct rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7435380`

Comment: How you are getting value from NSArray?

Comment: As i shown above the `myArray` will prints out as NSLoglike this  `success; products=<AGSProducts 0x7189020; name='category1';imageIdentifier='1'; imageUrlString='http://myimage.com/images/img1.png'; subProducts=>`

Comment: i thought you are accessing string from array, but some how your trying this on NSArray i guess.

Comment: No bhargavi i just tried with parsing an XML file and getting the image links from it. I parsed and thrown the elements into array and from that i tried to get the image url's